# Entity framework relationship issue 'Unable to determine the principal end...'

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having two classes, like below

```
Class One 
{
  ID (PK),
  Property 2;
}

Class Two
{
  ID (PK),
  One_ID (FK),
  Nullable_One_ID (FK)
}
```

While saving I am getting error `' Unable to determine the principal end of the 'x' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.'`

I tried many combinations `WithOutPrincipal` and `WithOutDependant` etc. But no luck, please guide me to the right relationship.

Comment: There can be either 1 or 2 `Class Two`s, but not 0 or more than 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to have 1 to 0 or 1 relationship between class one and class two then  you need to have  primary key and foriegn key same in class 2 and it should be primary key of class one

Class One { ID (PK), Property 2; }

Class Two { One_ID (PK, FK), Nullable_One_ID (FK) }

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, and you might want to provide more detail, but I suspect that you want only one foreign key property on your class two. Depending on how you're creating these objects, this may also be happening because you're trying to reference an id that's 0, because the object has not yet been saved to the database, so it has not been assigned an id.